# Given hcf and lcm find two numbers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $G$ and $L$ be given positive integers.
Prove that integers $x$ and $y$ exist satisfying $gcd(x,y)=G$ and $lcm[x,y]=L$ if and only if $G|L$.

My attempt:

$$x=\prod _{i=1}^kp_i^{\alpha _i}$$

$$y=\prod _{i=1}^kp_i^{\beta _i}$$

and

$$G=gcd(x,y)=\prod _{ i=1 }^{ k }{ { p }_{ i }^{ \min { { (\alpha  }_{ i },{ \beta  }_{ i }) }  } } $$

$$L=lcm(x,y)=\prod _{ i=1 }^{ k }{ { p }_{ i }^{ \max { { (\alpha  }_{ i },{ \beta  }_{ i }) }  } } $$

where ${ p }_{ i }$ is the ${ i }^{ th }$ prime number and $\alpha _i\ ,\ \beta _i\ge 0$

Now, $L=G\cdot q+r$ and 
G|L if and only if $r=0$ and

$$q=\prod _{i=1}^kp_i^{\left(\max \left(\alpha _i,\beta _i\right)-\min \left(\alpha _i,\beta _i\right)\right)}$$

What shall I do next?
Is this complete/incomplete or a fiasco?
Help me, thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE @Neeraj Snappy. do you see $\surd$ under " Anurag A "'s answer? if you mark it, it means that you accepted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

($ \Rightarrow $)
By definition: $gcd(x,y)=G$ so $G|x$ and $lcm[x,y]=L$ so $x|L$. Hence $G|L$.

> "|" is transitive: $G|x$ and $x|L$. So x=Ga and L=xb. Hence L=G(ab); which means $G|L$

---

($\Leftarrow$)
 $L=Gc$ then $gcd(G,Gc)=?$ and $lcm[G,Gc]=?$

Answer (score 0):

If $g=\gcd(x,y)$ and $l=\text{lcm}(x,y)$, then by definition $g | x$ and $x | l$, therefore by transitivity, $g | l$.

To prove the other way. Let $l=gk$. Then consider $x=g$ and $y=gk$.